# ajax get method working with mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, jquery-mobile

```
function categories_get() {
    $this->load->database();
    $sql = 'SELECT genre AS Genre, COUNT(*) AS Records FROM games ';
    $sql .= 'GROUP BY genre;'   ;
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $data = $query->result();   
    $this->response(json_encode($data),200);
}
```

I have a MySQL Database which has stored Games along with the genre of the game.

I have the above PHP function working and tested using the APIGEE Console and it is outputting JSON data.

http://creative.coventry.ac.uk/~4089797/Games/V1.0/index.php/games/categories

I have tried a few different methods but I can't figure out how to output this data dynamically onto a listview in JQM.

```
<li><a href="#resultspage1" data-transition="slideup" onclick="Get()">Get Games All Categories</a></li>
```

This is how it is called:

```
function Get(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://creative.coventry.ac.uk/~4089797/Games/V1.0/index.php/games/categories',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
```

The bit I'm stuck on is here. This is what I've tried but with no luck.

```
        $('#output1').append('<li><a href="" data-transition="slideup" 
            onclick="Getgames('+genre+')">'+genre+'
            <div class="ui-li-count">'+genre.records+'</div>
            </a><li>'
        );
```

I know I've done it wrong but I'm not sure where.

The table that its getting the data from is called `games` and has `id, title, ean, genre, developer`

```
        },
        error: function (response) {
            var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
            alert("Message: " + r.Message);
        }
    });
}
```

Thats the function as I've so far but I'm not sure what to use to get the data to display to this list view

```
    <ul id="output1" data-role="listview"> </ul>
```

Comment: I don't see where the method is called. You make a GET request to a certain page (maybe that contains the mthod?), but there's no method call in order to retrieve the json return

Comment: sorry forgot to include that i do have it i have edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
        $('#output1').append('<li><a href="" data-transition="slideup" 
            onclick="Getgames('+genre+')">'+genre+'
            <div class="ui-li-count">'+genre.records+'</div>
            </a><li>'
        );
```

has a flaw. You cannot just insert a newline in a string, expecting it to continue. You have to place a backslash to indicate that the newline is actually part of the string (so not spaces after the backslash!).

```
        $('#output1').append('<li><a href="" data-transition="slideup" \
            onclick="Getgames('+genre+')">'+genre+'\
            <div class="ui-li-count">'+genre.records+'</div>\
            </a><li>'
        );
```

Much better.

You also weren't looping through the JSON data you received, which is assumed to be an array of objects containing 'Genre' and 'Records' as members (case sensitive!). I fixed that for you as well as adding a jQuery click trigger instead of a 'onclick' attribute to the button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // get button, get game categories
    $("#getbutton").click(function() {  
        $.ajax({
            // make sure this URL is local to your server!
            // otherwise browsers may prevent this since it may be dangerous to load external sources
            url: 'http://creative.coventry.ac.uk/~4089797/Games/V1.0/index.php/games/categories',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                // loop through data array elements
                for(var i in data) {
                    // for each, append to the list
                    $('#output1').append('<li><a href="" data-transition="slideup"\
                        onclick="Getgames('+data[i].Genre+')">'+data[i].Genre+'\
                        <div class="ui-li-count">'+data[i].Records+'</div>\
                        </a><li>'
                    );
                }
            },
            error: function (response) {
                var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                alert("Message: " + r.Message);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The only change you have to make to your HTML is to add `id="getbutton"` to the button like so (and delete the `onclick` attribute):

```
<li><a id="getbutton" href="#resultspage1" data-transition="slideup">Get Games All Categories</a></li>
```

Comment: $.each(data.genres, function(i,genre)   i have managed to get it working using that line of code and it is doing the same as a loop and this way i managed to keep the onclick attribute and loaded the results page with javascript instead of html

Comment: also i knew that the code had to be on one line but for the purposes of this i started it on a new line which was wrong. I didnt know you could use the \ symbol to carry on a line of code... this is going to save me the trouble of a lot of messy code so thanks